# Find and draw the domain of function.

Tags: functions

please could you help us. We have to find and draw the domain of function:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\ln\left(y\cos (\pi x)\right)}$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are talking about $\Bbb R$.

First $y \cos(\pi x) > 0$ is a restriction, otherwise we can't take $\ln$. Therefore $y \neq 0$ is the first restriction.

Consider $\cos(\pi x)$. When $x\in \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb Z} (\frac{4n+1}{2},\frac{4n+3}{2}), \cos(\pi x)<0$, then $y<0$. When $x\in \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb Z} (\frac{4n-1}{2},\frac{4n+1}{2}), \cos(\pi x)>0$, then $y>0$. This is like upper half infinite rectangle follow by lower half infinite rectangle and so on. (Sorry for my bad English) Notice $x \neq n+\frac{1}{2}, n \in \Bbb Z$ is required. (Otherwise $\cos (\pi x) = 0$)

Also we don't what $y \cos(\pi x) = 1$ since this will make the denominator $0$. Notice that $\sec \theta \cos \theta = 1$. Therefore $y \neq \sec(\pi x)$.

The combined restrictions lead to the domain of $f$.